# Reading file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I  have a task  to convert the code from vb6 to vb.net.i am using streamreader for this ,
here is the  code i am using streamreader for this

```
    s = FTextStream.Read(1)
  Do While s <> ","
    If s <> Chr(34) And s <> Chr(10) Then
        MSymbol = MSymbol + s
    End If
    s = FTextStream.Read(1)
  Loop
  ProgressBar1.Value = 10
```

please guide me how do i achieve this in vb.net

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Can you show us the VB6 code you are trying to replicate?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What happens when you compile and run that code? And what do you actually want the code to do?

Comment: It looks more like poorly written VBScript that somebody dumped into VB6.  I'd hate to see the rest of the code in that program.  Maybe just start from scratch?